# Authorization and fetching data from api in ruby

Tags: ruby, authentication

I am trying to hit an API to fetch values, but the api prompts me for authentication where I shoud provide username and password.
I if try with some other APIs, I am able to get the data. Wondering how to do this authentication. I am pretty new to Ruby and this is how I am doing:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

result = JSON.parse(open("http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=london&maxRows=10&username=demo").read)
puts "#{result}"
```

Comment: How does the service authenticate? Is it basic HTTP or is it cookie-based?

Comment: @Slicedpan : Its basic HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this service, but most probably you can try [Basic Authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters)

```
result = JSON.parse(open("http://username:password@api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=london&maxRows=10&username=demo").read)
```

As @Slicedpan suggested, you can also use `open`s `options` [arguments](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#method-i-open):

```
result = JSON.parse(open("http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=london&maxRows=10&username=demo", :http_basic_authentication=>['user', 'password']).read)
```

If you get SSL errors, look at this [blog post](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html):

> Errors
>   --- Have you seen one of these error messages?
>
> ```
> openssl::ssl::sslerror: ssl_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=sslv3 read server certificate b: certificate verify failed
>
> could not load openssl. you must recompile ruby with openssl support or change the sources in your gemfile from 'https' to 'http'.
> ```
>
> instructions for compiling with openssl using rvm are available at
>   rvm.io/packages/openssl.
>
> Use RVM to Fix SSL Certificates
>   --- Recent versions of RVM, the [Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.io), include a utility to diagnose and resolve errors caused by outdated
>   certificate files. See the article [Installing
>   Rails](http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html) for
>   instructions and advice. The RVM website explains [how to install
>   RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/).
>
> If you’ve installed RVM, try this:
>
> ```
> $ rvm -v
> # rvm 1.19.1 (stable)
> $ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
> # Certificates for...
> $ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
> # Updating certificates...
> ```

Comment: Alternately, the open function accepts an argument for HTTP basic auth, consult the docs http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#method-i-open

Comment: @uriagassi I am getting this error my one API but it works for others. `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

Comment: Added explanation for SSL failure